# Limit visibility of records

Tags: administration, assignment-rules, sharing-rule, visibility

I have `sObject` for example `Account`, with records.

And two users `John` and `Jack`.

I want show to this users part of records, by using criteria.

Something like, John show records with `Account.Name = Zara`,

and Jack show records with  `Account.date=something`

How it possible?

How do this from triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve it.

1. make account object private
2. create sharing rule as per your criteria. for ex. `Account.Name = Zara` then   share record with John
3. Create other sharing rules as per your requirements

Comment: Its good, 
But what, if i want use record from another sObject for criteria

Comment: Apex based sharing rule can be the option. Refer the details and example in below link. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm

Answer (score 0):

Organization-wide sharing defaults set the baseline access for your records. You can set the defaults separately for different objects.

You need to set Organization-Wide Sharing setting as Private for Account and need to open up Access to Account record using Criteria-based sharing rules.

Criteria-based sharing rules determine whom to share records with based on field values in records.

[OWD Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en)

[Criteria-based sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en)